# Send email from game on libGDX engine on Android device?

Tags: java, android, email, libgdx

In my debug version of game, I want to take actual information about game progress from many users on my email. As you know, code in libGDX is writing on native Java without Android context. What suggestions do you know for my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this page on the libgdx wiki: [Interfacing with platform specific code](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationPlatformSpecific).
What you need to do is create an interface with the methods you need. Then create a class implementing that interface in your Android project. (And other projects if needed, if not needed, just create dummy-files that do nothing)
Then instantiate that proper class where you launch your game, and pass in the object to the game and use it there.

Just follow the guide, and then you can use Android stuff in your game (through an interface).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [ACRA (Application Crash Report for Android)](http://code.google.com/p/acra/). It automaticly sends you crash reports about every error in your application, that is very usefull by itself. And as I see it has [method to declare your own varibles which will be send](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#Adding_your_own_variables_content_or_traces_in_crash_reports). That may be what you want. Also it's [recommended by libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ACRA).